# Not able to connect to database with connection string in app.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, connection-string

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Transactions");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
{
   SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("[dbo].[GetFullTransactionList]", conn);
   sqlComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
   da.SelectCommand = sqlComm;
   da.Fill(ds);
}

return ds;
```

Relevant content of `app.config`:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="myConnectionString"
           connectionString="Data Source=LAPTOP-LT;Initial Catalog=myDb;User ID=sa;Password=abc"
           providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I'm getting this exception:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0. Description: An unhandled exception occurred
>   during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about the error and where it
>   originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the
>   initialization string does not conform to specification starting at
>   index 0.

Source Error:

```
Line 44:             DataSet ds = new DataSet("Transactions");
Line 45:             using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("myConnectionString"))
```

Comment: is [dbo].[GetFullTransactionList] stored procedure require any argument to be passed?

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to refer a connection string in the app.config is:

```
string cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourCnnString"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
{ 

}
```

do not forget the final property `ConnectionString`

Comment: its not able to access the connection string from the App.config

Comment: What do you mean? Do you have any kind of error message? Do you include `using System.Configuration;`?

Comment: It gives a null reference exception. yes i have included using System.configuration;

Comment: The only possibility that I can think to is the string `youCnnString`. This should be your `myConnectionString`

Answer (score 0):

To use connection string from config file, you need to access it `ConfigurationManager`.

So it will be:

```
   using (SqlConnection conn = new 
     SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"]))
   {
          ...
   }
```

Refer to [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) to get more info

Answer (score 0):

SqlConnection expect a real connection string not the key from app.config. Try to read it with

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString
```